# Label custom NER in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: `'text', 'in', 'tar'` of `type(str, list, list)` respectively.

```
                   text                                       in       tar
0  This is an example text that I use in order to  ...       [2]       [6]
1  Discussion: We are examining the possibility of ...       [3]     [6, 7]
```

`in` and `tar` represent specific entities that I want to tag into the text, and they return the position of each found entity term in the text.

For example, at the 2nd row of the dataframe where `in = [3]`, I want to take the 3rd word from `text` column (i.e.: *"are"*) and label it as `<IN>are</IN>`.

Similarly, for the same row, since `tar = [6,7]`, I also want to take the 6th and 7th word from `text` column (i.e. *"possibility"*, *"of"*) and label them as  `<TAR>possibility</TAR>`, `<TAR>of</TAR>`.

Can someone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most optimal implementation but is worth getting inspiration.

```
data = {'text': ['This is an example text that I use in order to',
                 'Discussion: We are examining the possibility of the'],
        'in': [[2], [3]],
        'tar': [[6], [6, 7]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cols = list(df.columns)[1:]
new_text = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    temp = list(row['text'].split())
    for pos, word in enumerate(temp):
        for col in cols:
            if pos in row[col]:
                temp[pos] = f'<{col.upper()}>{word}</{col.upper()}>'
    new_text.append(' '.join(temp))
df['text'] = new_text
print(df.text.to_list())
```

output:

```
['This is <IN>an</IN> example text that <TAR>I</TAR> use in order to', 
 'Discussion: We are <IN>examining</IN> the possibility <TAR>of</TAR> <TAR>the</TAR>']
```

**UPDATE 1**

Merging consecutive occurrence of the similar tags can be done like below:

```
data = {'text': ['This is an example text that I use in order to',
                 'Discussion: We are examining the possibility of the'],
        'in': [[2], [3, 4, 5]],
        'tar': [[6], [6, 7]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cols = list(df.columns)[1:]
new_text = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    temp = list(row['text'].split())
    for pos, word in enumerate(temp):
        for col in cols:
            if pos in row[col]:
                temp[pos] = f'<{col.upper()}>{word}</{col.upper()}>'
    new_text.append(' '.join(temp))
    
df['text'] = new_text
for col in cols:
    df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda text:text.replace("</"+col.upper()+"> <"+col.upper()+">", " "))
print(df.text.to_list())
```

output:

```
['This is <IN>an</IN> example text that <TAR>I</TAR> use in order to', 'Discussion: We are <IN>examining the possibility</IN> <TAR>of the</TAR>']
```

Comment: Thank you @meti. Can I also ask you, if instead of tagging each element of the 'tar' separately, I wanted to tag them together, such as: <TAR>possibility of</TAR>, how could I do that?

Comment: This can be done using REGEX, I would update the solution ASAP. @joasa